# How to use a canvas parameter in a __init__ function of a class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made this module called gamesmodule, and I am working on a program that makes a ball spawn and bounce in the canvas. I used a

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill='red')
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 25, 25)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -1
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width
```

and the init function contained a canvas parameter, which to enter a canvas name. I had predefined the canvas, and created the ball in the class:

```
ball = Ball(canvas)
```

but the Python shell outputted this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#59>", line 1, in <module>
 ball = Ball(canvas)
 NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. You need to indent all lines from the line starting with `self.id` to the end by one more level. As it is, only `self.canvas = canvas` is inside of the `__init__` method

Comment: Thank you. I now fixed that.

Comment: In your code, have you defined something named `canvas`? The error seems pretty self-explanatory. Also, `self.canvas.winfo_height` needs to be `self.canvas.winfo_height()` (and same for width). These are functions, not properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `canvas`

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(...)

ball = Ball(canvas)
```

Maybe you define `canvas` in wrong place  - ie. in some function - and it is not availabe when you execute `Ball(canvas)`

Answer (score 1):

Python uses whitespace (indentation) to define the limits of a code block. You need to align all the lines inside `__init__`:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        # Lines below this one were unindented in your example:
        self.id = self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill='red')
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 25, 25)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -1
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width
```

This is not generating your error, however. Look at the description:

```
ball = Ball(canvas)
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

The variable `canvas` is not defined in the block where you call `Ball(canvas)`. Python doesn't know what `canvas` means in that context.

Comment: That unindentation was a copy error, a mistake I made copying the code.

Comment: Edited, you are missing a definition